# Double Filtering in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to join all data according to GroupIDs, which these GroupIDs are owned by EmpNo

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeWithEmail> GetAllEmployeesWithEmail(int EmpNo)
{
    using (var context = new SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1())
    {
        return (from ea in context.View_SystemAdminMembers
                join vh in context.View_HCM on (Int16)ea.EmpNo equals vh.EmpNo
                join rl in context.EmployeeAccessLevels on ea.RoleID equals rl.id into outer_join
                from subjoin in outer_join 

              //need code to join all data according to EmpNo's GroupIDs

                group new
                {
                    ea.EmpNo,
                    subjoin.Role,
                    vh.EmailAddress,
                    vh.LNameByFName,
                    ea.Active

                } by vh.LNameByFName into grp
                let item = grp.FirstOrDefault()
                orderby item.Role ascending
                select new EmployeeWithEmail
                {
                    EmpNum = item.EmpNo ?? 0,
                    Role = item.Role,
                    EmailAddress = item.EmailAddress,
                    LNameByFname = item.LNameByFName,
                    Active2 = item.Active ?? false

                }).ToList();

    }
}
```

I guess I'm trying to filter twice and join common data, but there are actually two filters, which I don't know how to control.

So my output would be like:

```
EmpNo --->  __  01 |  01 |  01 | 01

GroupID --->  __10 |  10 |  20 | 20

Data ---> _________Apple | Apple | Orange | Orange
```

I can filter EmpNo 01 and GroupID 10 but **What if the EmpNo belongs to two groups?**
Sorry for not finding the right terminologies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to write a T-SQL statement that would give you what you want?  If so, what would that be?  (That would help me better understand what you are after)

Comment: I purely coded in LINQ as I'm very new to it especially to SQL. But anyway I'll make a view in a moment.

Comment: SELECT     dbo.EmployeeAccess.EmpNo, dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.LNameByFName AS Expr1, dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.GroupName AS Expr2, 
                      dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.Role AS Expr3, dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.Active, dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.EmpNo AS Expr4, 
                      dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.RoleID
FROM         dbo.EmployeeAccess INNER JOIN
                      dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers ON dbo.EmployeeAccess.GroupID = dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.GroupID
WHERE     (dbo.EmployeeAccess.EmpNo = '01')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, the SQL you are trying to generate should be (I've simplified slightly)

```
SELECT EmployeeAccess.EmpNo, View_SystemAdminMembers.LNameByFName, View_SystemAdminMembers.GroupName,
        View_SystemAdminMembers.Role, View_SystemAdminMembers.Active, View_SystemAdminMembers.EmpNo, 
        View_SystemAdminMembers.RoleID 
FROM EmployeeAccess 
    INNER JOIN View_SystemAdminMembers ON EmployeeAccess.GroupID = View_SystemAdminMembers.GroupID 
WHERE (EmployeeAccess.EmpNo = '01')
```

This is pretty different from what you show in your question:

```
from ea in context.View_SystemAdminMembers
     join vh in context.View_HCM on (Int16)ea.EmpNo equals vh.EmpNo
     join rl in context.EmployeeAccessLevels on ea.RoleID equals rl.id into outer_join
     from subjoin in outer_join
```

so I'm not sure if my answer is going to help or not, but to get the SQL you specify, I think you would want to do:

```
var query =
from ea in context.EmployeeAccess
join vsam in context.View_SystemAdminMembers on ea.GroupID equals vsam.GroupID
where ea.EmpNo == "01"
select new
{
    ea.EmpNo, vsam.LNameByFName, vsam.GroupName, vsam.Role, vsam.Active, vsam.EmpNo, vsam.RoleID
};
```

Using fluent syntax (not query syntax) it would look a bit like:

```
var query =
    context.EmployeeAccess
    .Join(context.View_SystemAdminMembers, allEA => allEA.GroupID, allVSAM => allVSAM.GroupID, (ea, vsam) => new {ea, vsam})
    .Where(combined => combined.ea.EmpNo == "01")
    .Select(combined => combined.ea.EmpNo, combined.vsam.LNameByFName, combined.vsam.GroupName, combined.vsam.Role, combined.vsam.Active, combined.vsam.EmpNo, combined.vsam.RoleID);
```

(although I admit--I normally return the whole entity like
`.Select(combined => combined.ea)` or something like that so I'm not 100% certain on that last line...)

Note that in both cases, "var query" is going to be an `IQueryable` which means you will still need to add a `ToList` or equivalent to get your results.  Before you do that, though, you'll want to apply Tim Burkhart's answer to make any modifications you want on it (like `GroupBy` or whatever).  As he noted, one of the cool things about `IQueryable` is that you don't have to do it all in one statement; you can take `query` just as I have defined it above and then add something like

```
query = query.Where(c => c.LNameByFName.Contains("A"))
```

or whatever.

One more note--your return value is entirely made up of items from View_SystemAdminMembers with the exception of EmployeeAccess.EmpNo, but since you are filtering on that, you should already know what it is.  It may be easier to return just a `View_SystemAdminMember` object, rather than creating a new type.  That's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really following what you're asking for. Perhaps it can be rephrased or given more context or formatted differently?

But I thought I would make some suggestions that might help you get to where you are wanting to go.

1 - The function name implies that the person will provide an email and receive multiple Employee objects with that email. But it appears to accept an employee id and return a list of EmployeeWithEmail. Consider renaming the function to match what it is doing. Also consider returning `IEnumerable<Employee>` or `IEnumerable<IEmployeeEmailView>`

2 - This function is doing a lot. (And it takes more than a few seconds to figure out what it is doing). In cases like this, I would start off simple. Don't do the grouping or sorting or anything. Have some function return the results of this:

```
from ea in context.View_SystemAdminMembers
join vh in context.View_HCM on (Int16)ea.EmpNo equals vh.EmpNo
join rl in context.EmployeeAccessLevels on ea.RoleID equals rl.id into outer_join
from subjoin in outer_join
```

in the form of something like `IEnumerable<Employee>`

```
public class Employee {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Role { get; set; }
     public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

From there, things are easier to deal with. You're not having to work with LINQ-to-SQL. You can just do...

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = <your renamed function>();
var employeesGroupedByName = employees.GroupBy(e => e.Name);
```

Hopefully that makes things easier for you. It doesn't solve your answer, but I think it might make things less complicated/easier to work with.

So written out fully, it could be something like:

```
public class EmployeeRepository {
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll() {
        // This function won't compile. I don't know the syntax for this type of LINQ
        using (var context = new SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1()) {
            return (from ea in context.View_SystemAdminMembers
            join vh in context.View_HCM on (Int16)ea.EmpNo
            join rl in context.EmployeeAccessLevels on ea.RoleID equals rl.id into outer_join
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployeesWithEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        return GetAll().Where(e => e.Id == employeeId).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> SomeOtherFunctionThatDoesWhatYouWantToDoFromThisPost() {
        // You could also create a class that extends IEnumerable<Employee> to
        // encapsulate the logic so that the repository doesn't have a million functions
    }
}
```

That's all I've got for you. I could give a more complete answer if the problem was spelled out a little bit better, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for that, yes I have declared a class such as yours. Also, I'm afraid to use lambda since I don't fully understand it. But okay I'll do my best to work my way around your code!

Comment: You should get to know lambdas. They are super easy to use and they are really powerful. They also allow for chained filtering.